# Unable to connect to API on local xampp server from android app (via emulator)

Tags: android, api, kotlin, xampp, fuel

I have a simple API written in PHP to interact with my MYSQL database. The API returns the correct response when I call it from the browser in the emulator but the request fails when its being done from the code.

```
package com.example.studenthealthapp
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.Fuel
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result
import org.json.JSONArray

class InfoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    setContentView(R.layout.info_layout)

    val api_url =
        "http://10.0.2.2:80/HealthTracker/api.php?email=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("email")
    //Toast.makeText(this,api_url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    Fuel.get(api_url).response { request, response, result ->

        when (result) {
            is Result.Success -> {
                //var data = JSONArray(String(response.data))
                //Toast.makeText(this,data.length().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            is Result.Failure -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Didnt work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

      }
   }
}
```

I have tried both my IP address and 10.0.2.2 when calling the API all of them has the same result.

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: @Swayangjit after logging the response this is what I got.

2022-04-21 00:15:29.247 11538-11538/com.example.studenthealthapp E/fail: <-- -1 http://10.0.2.2/HealthTracker/api.php?email=ruab.osan1@gmail.com
    Response : 
    Length : 0
    Body : (empty)
    Headers : (0)

Comment: I logged the request and saw that there were no headers. 2022-04-21 00:21:04.566 12081-12081/com.example.studenthealthapp E/request: --> GET http://10.0.2.2/HealthTracker/api.php?email=ruab.osan1@gmail.com
    Body : (empty)
    Headers : (0).

Could this be the issue?

Comment: The error returned by Fuel says "Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have run into this problem before and your solutions may lie in one of two options. I don't recommend the first as it sets a bad precedent for future projects.

1. The first would be to allow "http://..." without the "s", also called clear text traffic in your apps manifest. A quick search on youtube will get you some outdated tutorials and this is probably not a good sign.
2. My preferred solution is that you switch from Volley to Retrofit. It has better up-to-date tutorials both on youtube and in articles on the web and is much easier to use. It might seem like starting from scratch but you'll be saving yourself from a lot of future headaches.

Good luck!